# Почему не срабатывает свойство зависимости?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь сделать так что бы команда DoubleClick срабатывала только по DataGridRow. Использую свойство зависимости:

```
public static DependencyProperty DoubleClickCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "DoubleClickCommand",
                typeof(ICommand),
                typeof(DataGridRowBehavior),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(DoubleClick_PropertyChanged));

public static void SetDoubleClickCommand(DependencyObject target, ICommand value)
{
      target.SetValue(DataGridRowBehavior.DoubleClickCommandProperty, value);
}

public static ICommand GetDoubleClickCommand(UIElement element)
{
      return (ICommand)element.GetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty);
}

private static void DoubleClick_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
      var element = target as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
      if (element == null)
      {
          throw new System.InvalidOperationException("This behavior can be attached to a DataGridRow item only.");
      }

      if ((e.NewValue != null) && (e.OldValue == null))
      {
           element.PreviewMouseDoubleClick += OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick;
      }
      else if ((e.NewValue == null) && (e.OldValue != null))
      {
           element.PreviewMouseDoubleClick -= OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick;
      }
}

private static void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      DependencyObject obj = sender as DependencyObject;
      ICommand cmd = (ICommand)obj.GetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty);
      if (cmd != null)
      {
           if (cmd.CanExecute(obj))
               cmd.Execute(obj);
      }
}
```

Во view у меня следующее:

```
.
.
.
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="help:DataGridRowBehavior.DoubleClickCommand" Value="{Binding local:EditProduct}" />
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
.
.
.
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyDG"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductCol}"
                          RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentProduct}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                          IsReadOnly="True">

</DataGrid>
```

А в ViewModel выглядет вот так:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Product currentProduct;

    public Product CurrentProduct
    {
        get 
        {
           return currentProduct; 
        }
        set 
        {
           currentProduct = value;
           Debug.WriteLine(currentProduct.Id);
           OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProduct");
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Product> product;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductCol
    {
        get
        {
            if (product == null)
                product = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            return product;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ProductCol.Add( new Product() {Id = 1, Code = 5236});
        ProductCol.Add(new Product() { Id = 2, Code = 2857 });
        ProductCol.Add(new Product() { Id = 3, Code = 7851 });
    }

    RelayCommand editProduct;
    public ICommand EditProduct
    {
        get
        {
            if (editProduct == null)
                editProduct = new RelayCommand(ExecuteEditCurrentProductCommand,
                        CanExecuteEditCurrentProductCommand);

            return editProduct;
        }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteEditCurrentProductCommand(object obj)
    {
        return CurrentProduct == null ? false : true;
    }

    private void ExecuteEditCurrentProductCommand(object obj)
    {
        var oEW = new ObjectEditorWindow();
        var vm = new ObjectEditorViewModel<Product>();
        vm.SelectedObject = CurrentProduct;
        oEW.DataContext = vm;
        oEW.ShowDialog();
    }

    protected override void OnDispose()
    {
        this.ProductCol.Clear();
    }
}
```

Обратил внимание на вот такую ошибку...

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'EditProduct' property not found on 'object' ''Product' (HashCode=53239939)'. BindingExpression:Path=EditProduct; DataItem='Product' (HashCode=53239939); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'DoubleClickCommand' (type 'ICommand')
```

Как я понимаю компилятор ищет свойство EditProduct в классе Product. Если это так, почему так происходит?Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Всё потому, что DataContext у DataGrid - коллекция Product. Естественно, что WPF ищет команду в нём, ведь вы так и написали. Вам надо переопределить DoubleClick на самом DataGrid, используя выбранный Product как аргумент команды.